# CakePHP cannot start missing intl PHP extension

Tags: php, macos, cakephp, php-extension

Can't get CakePHP to start on Mac after trying the following - php is running ok otherwise:
I tried reinstalling php@7.3 on MacOS and change php.ini to enable intl

php -m => intl module shows installed

I tried the following suggestion - but cannot find intl.so anywhere:
First off, if your OS is Linux/macOS and the PHP extension is a shared library (i.e. has a .so extension) then the php.ini entry should be extension=intl.so not extension=php_intl.dll. Also make sure the intl.so file is in the directory configured under the ini entry extension_dir. Otherwise make sure the extension ini entry is fully qualified (e.g. extension=/path/to/extension/dir/intl.so).

Comment: Did you restart the server (Apache, Nginx or CakePHP's own serve script) after you updated the php.ini file?

Comment: Yes everytime. 
intl module shows installed and enabled
php --ri intl

Internationalization support => enabled
ICU version => 67.1
ICU Data version => 67.1
ICU TZData version => 2019c
ICU Unicode version => 13.0

Directive => Local Value => Master Value
intl.default_locale => no value => no value
intl.error_level => 0 => 0
intl.use_exceptions => 0 => 0

Comment: Do you get the same if you create a php page that calls `phpinfo()` and access it from a browser? Calling PHP from the commandline on some installations uses a different php.ini file than the one used by the webserver.

Comment: Add a file and do a `phpinfo()` call to it. See the path to the ini file. Often times, the php.ini used for the command line is different from the one used for a web server.